# Custom Material Problem in Forge with Revit 2017

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, revit, autodesk-model-derivative

I followed the instructions in the [blog post on custom materials in forge](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/show-revit-custom-texture-map-viewer) and got it to work with Revit 2019.

However, with Revit 2017 (I had to update it first to get the "Publish Settings" in the Collaboration tab), the completely same approach did not work and the translation failed with the following manifest message:

```
{
   "type":"manifest",
   "hasThumbnail":"false",
   "status":"failed",
   "progress":"complete",
   "region":"US",
   "urn":"dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0...",
   "version":"1.0",
   "derivatives":[
      {
         "name":"001_010_020_Gras_dicht_bump.jpg",
         "hasThumbnail":"false",
         "status":"failed",
         "progress":"complete",
         "messages":[
            {
               "type":"error",
               "code":"Revit-UnsupportedFileType",
               "message":"<message>The file is not a Revit file or is not a supported version.</message>"
            },
            {
               "type":"error",
               "message":"Possibly recoverable warning exit code from extractor: -536870935",
               "code":"TranslationWorker-RecoverableInternalFailure"
            }
         ],
         "outputType":"svf"
      }
   ]
}
```

The translation seems to fail because Forge does not know what to do with the image. When first trying with Revit 2019 I got the same error, but managed to resolve it by specifying a realistic 3d view for the Set in the Publish Settings. This seems to tell Forge it needs the images for creating the textures.

But for some reason, this wont work with 2017, although I make the exact same call, and have the exact same settings.. am I missing something, or doing something wrong? Is Revit 2017 handling its Publish Settings differently, or are custom textures not supported in Forge for Revit 2017 files?

I am thankful for any hint or help in this case.

Comment: Usually the `Revit-UnsupportedFileType` indicates a corrupted file, can you try upload and translate again?

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves yes, I tried it several times in the process of isolating the error, with different textures and rvt files. no other outcome, translation fails with the first image that is "touched"

Comment: are you able to share a non-confidential model (2017 and 2019) that demonstrate the issue? that way I can try to reproduce here. Please do not send any trade secret information. If possible, use forge.help[at]autodesk.com

Comment: would also help to have the URN for the 2017 model that fails, we can check the logs

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves i have just sent you a mail. thanks!

Comment: got it, thanks @jakobn

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves do you have any news for me regarding this issue? I have already tried contacting you via the email above.

Comment: yes I got the files, sorry I don't have relevant updates yet, although is on our queue. Sorry the extra time.

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves thanks for the response. Please keep me updated if you know more :)

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves any updates?